# Блокировка при парсинге Bitrix PHP

Tags: php, парсер, битрикс, curl

Пишу парсер для проекта, если коротко, то он собирает лист товаров с сайта на Bitrix, а после выводит нужную информацию.

Парсер использует CURL. После первого сбора ссылок на товары мне начало выдавать ошибку на любой запрос получить страницу сайта - получил блокировку. Скрипт для сбора проходит около 100 страниц.

Что я сделал:

- добавил задержку перед каждым запросом (случайно от 1 до 7 сек),
- купил 4 ip адреса, менял их также перед каждым запросом случайно,
- добавил имитацию браузера `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');`

Таким способом у меня получилось два раза отправить запрос на сбор ссылок, после опять блокировка. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: сайт на битриксе ваш или нет?

Comment: не нужно "иммитировать", используйте реальное имя браузера. Хотя это вряд ли очень поможет. Лучше договоритесь с собственниками/админами сайта. Это будет дешевле, безопаснее и легальнее

Answer (score 0):

Используй Python Selenium. Никакие имитации не помогут. Будут потом банить через куки потом проверять имитацию движения мыши и.т.д. - Там мозги работают над этим.  Всё это обходить Selenium Driver, ровно в 10 строчек кода. Даже Яндекс не устоял. Когда Selenium сохранит все страницы, - Нужно будит лишь их прочитать парсером php. Всё...